# by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors the evaluate the following.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

so the question is : by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix 
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}1&6\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{evaluate }P^{20}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I can sort out how I will evaluate the second part.

eigenvalue$=-2$; eigenvector$=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

eigenvalue$=1$; eigenvector$=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Thank you in advance.
Hugo

Comment: There are directions in the FAQ section to write properly mathematics in this site with LaTex. Please follow them.

Comment: Eigenvectors are non-zero vectors. The eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ should be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad representation of my question. thanks @robjohn for fixing that !! :D

Comment: It would be helpful to see your attempt at the problem, so we can properly gauge where the problem is, rather than giving you a full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments, that this was very hard to read and I hope I understood it properly.

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = -2, v_1 = (-2, 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = 1, v_2 = (1, 0)$$

Next, we can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$P = S J S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

What do you notice about $J$? What is it made from?

What do you notice about the columns of $P$? What is it made from?

Now that we have the Jordan Normal Form (diagonalized matrix), we can use to find the matrix power:

$$P^{20} = \left(S J S^{-1}\right)^{20} = \left(S J^{20} S^{-1}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{20} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, a diagonal matrix to a power is just each value of that diagonal entry to that power, so we get:

$$P^{20} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1048576 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

You can now just multiply that out for the final result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! I completely got it now thanks.

Comment: @hugonicolasadario: You are very welcome. I should have also mentioned that there are other ways to do this, but I was trying to use your approach to provide guidance. Regards

Comment: Good job, Amzoti! Nice feedback, too! +1

Comment: Hmmm...slow...a few questions I've answered...but need something to did my teeth into!

Comment: Yes, I agree. And the OPs whom I've answered seem to have gone "awol" this evening!

Comment: I seem to have that affect on postings I responded to, they run for the hills! :-)